# Nanocellulose suspension in water being dialysed in ethanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

I am working on nanocellulose. To prepare the sample for silanization, the first step is to dialyse the preparation in ethanol overnight. I wonder why this is a necessary step. Sorry, I am a physicist working on something which involves a lot of chemistry. I am alone in my lab so I don't know who else to ask. Thank you very much!

Comment: Where did you get the preparation instructions?

Comment: Hello. My prof gave me the protocol.  I didn't ask but my guess is that it is a solubility issue w/ the silane. Thanks for the reply